# How to implement "trigger" for redis datastore?

Tags: triggers, nosql, redis

I have a program, which will poll on a certain key from the redis datastore, and do something when the value satisfies a certain condition.

However, I think periodically polling on redis is quite inefficient, I'm wondering if there is a "trigger" mechanism for redis, when the value changes and satisfies the condition, the trigger will be called. The trigger might be a RPC function, or an HTTP msg, or something else, so that I don't need to poll on it any more, just like the difference between poll and interrupt.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the [Pub/Sub](http://redis.io/topics/pubsub) feature of Redis. It's exactly what you need given your circumstances as you described.

Essentially, you `SUBSCRIBE` to a "channel", and the other part of your application writes (`PUBLISH`) the value being changed to that channel. Your subscriber (consumer, the client that wants to know about the change) will get notified in virtually realtime.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've read the documentation of Pub/Sub feature of Redis, but still don't understand how to trigger when a value changes. Who will do the "Pub" action? Without polling on the value, how to trigger the "Pub" action?

Comment: The client which is writing the values should publish that the values have changed.

Comment: @ciphor if I understand your question, the idea is to change your application logic, so instead of (or in addition to) writing your value to a "plain" redis key, you write it to the channel, so that every subscriber (can be one of course) is immediately notified.

Comment: Good idea, it would be great if firebase supports the trigger and stored procedure like this. especially asynchronous trigger(to deduplicate actions in a short period)

Answer (score 7):

Since Redis 2.8 ([released](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/2.8/00-RELEASENOTES#L585) 22 Nov 2013), there is now a feature called [Keyspace Notifications](https://redis.io/topics/notifications) which lets clients subscribe to special Pub/Sub channels for keyspace events, which you can use as a trigger on a certain key.

The feature is disabled by default because "while not very sensible the feature uses some CPU power." To enable, send a [`CONFIG SET`](https://redis.io/commands/config-set) command to [configure](https://redis.io/topics/notifications#configuration) the feature. For example, the following command will enable keyspace events for String commands:

```
> CONFIG SET notify-keyspace-events K$
OK
```

Next, use the regular pubsub [`SUBSCRIBE`](https://redis.io/commands/subscribe) command to subscribe to the specially-named channel. For example, to listen to keyspace events on the `mykey` key in DB 0:

```
> SUBSCRIBE __keyspace@0__:mykey
Reading messages... (press Ctrl-C to quit)
```

Test out the feature by setting the key's value from another client:

```
> SET mykey myvalue
OK
```

You should receive a message in the subscribed client:

```
1) "message"
2) "__keyspace@0__:mykey"
3) "set"
```

After receiving the event, you can fetch the updated value and see if it satisfies the condition in your application code.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use Pub/Sub, that's best.  If for some reason that doesn't work, you could also use the (performance-impacting) `MONITOR` command, which will send you every command the server receives.  That's probably not a good idea.

Specifically for lists, you have `BLPOP`, which will block the connection until a new item is available to pop from a list.

Answer (score 0):

How about a message box to deal with?For example, 2 message (AND operation) could trigger another message, I think this could make some point? Like JBPM, but not complex than that.

Comment: Maybe we could add hooks in each message which check another message is condition available before and after.