# Can redis call an HTTP endpoint on key update?

Tags: redis, google-cloud-functions, publish-subscribe, serverless, endpoint

Redis has a key update notification system but I don't see a way to tell it to call an API endpoint when a key is updated. It seems more like a pub/sub setup. In my case, that API endpoint is a serverless Google Cloud Function. Can redis do this?

I've seen [How to implement "trigger" for redis datastore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475547/how-to-implement-trigger-for-redis-datastore), but that recommends pub/sub with a subscriber continuously running to receive change messages.

What I'm looking for is for redis itself to call an external HTTP endpoint when something happens. Specifically, a serverless Google Cloud function, which isn't running all the time. The function only "wakes up" on a request so it can't be a Redis subscriber. Hence my question about calling arbitrary HTTP endpoints.

Comment: You're still describing a "trigger", which is covered by that other question.

Comment: OK, so the answer is "no"?

Comment: If it didn't show up in the question that I previously marked as a duplicate, I can only assume no such feature exists.  I'd recommend looking into the solution they provide and engineer it so that an outgoing message can trigger some code to make the request.